# What method can filter two pairs of data using filter() or other recommanded way?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

[image]

I want to use filter() to search from `B2:B` corresponding to
the range like `F2:F3`

I use `=filter(A2:A,B2:B = F2:F3)`,but there is just one data `Jack`

I know this example can using FILTER to do the same thing like this.
[image]

But now if there is a lot of data, it may not meet my needs.

Then I use `=ArrayFormula(filter(A2:A,B2:B = F2:F3))`

And it's not useful, too. (I don't know how to use `arrayformula()` methods)

What should I fix the formula and parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) to check whether the values `B2:B` are included in the range `F2:F3`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,COUNTIF(F2:F3,B2:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much,it's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:B; REGEXMATCH(B2:B; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; F2:F)))
```

or:

```
=QUERY(A2:B; "select A,B where B matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; F2:F)&"'"; 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
You helped me a lot half years ago,I remembered.